# Sass priority with :hover and classes

Tags: css, sass

I'm writing a stylesheet for a tab list used multiple times in the page, which has a style for unselected tabs, tabs hovered over, and tabs selected. The problem is that the hover style is prioritized over the selected style when hovering over a selected item. Here's my stylesheet:

```
@mixin bg-rgba($r, $g, $b, $a) {
  background: rgb($r, $g, $b);
  background: rgba($r, $g, $b, $a);
}

@mixin tab-inactive {
  background: none;
  color: rgb(68, 7, 114);
}

@mixin tab-hover {
  @include bg-rgba(68, 7, 114, 0.875);
  color: white;
}

@mixin tab-selected {
  @include bg-rgba(57, 12, 145, 0.875);
  color: white;
}

.tabbar {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  @include bg-rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.625);

  &-item {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    @include tab-inactive;

    &:hover {
      @include tab-hover;
    }

    // including &.active:hover doesn't work
    // using :active also isn't feasible
    &.active {
      @include tab-selected;
    }
  }
}
```

When I don't use the mixins and copy paste the three styles for each tabbar item everywhere i use it, it works, but how can I do this with mixins, by extending, or through some other method I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see an issue with your code - it currently renders as:

```css
.tabbar-item:hover {
  background: #440772;
  background: rgba(68, 7, 114, 0.875);
  color: white;
}

.tabbar-item.active {
  background: #390c91;
  background: rgba(57, 12, 145, 0.875);
  color: white;
}
```

As long as the hover rule is above the active rule, the active rule should be applied.

Comment: On my end, the compiled version places the active rule above the hover rule, even though that's not how they're placed in the SCSS stylesheet.

Comment: Oh, I see what I did wrong. I tried extending from styles instead of mixins, but placed the active one before the hover one.

Comment: If you can't reproduce a problem, the question should be closed as not reproducible.  "Your code works fine" is not an answer.

Comment: I agree with you. I'm aware that "nvm fixed" is the worst kind of answer I could've given. What was making the problem reproducible on my end was the gulp watch script I was using not changing the order of the styles after I had fixed it. I'll keep in mind to run gulp build in cases like this just to make sure it is a problem.